# PHP Codeigniter error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using a php mysql based crm software which is made using Codeigniter.
I don't have any knowledge about Codeigniter.
I just customized it as per my requirements.

Whenever I am trying to save any data I am getting this error.

[image]
While using in Xampp I did not get these errors.
When I put it online I started to get these. Also I tried to ignore PHP errors, warnings using

error_reporting(0); 
in my controller/admin.php

This would just hide the errors and not ignore them and proceed to the redirected page after the save.

If anything else is needed please let me know.

Comment: @castis : I did but frankly they were ignored when working offline and I just wanted the same here. The data does get saved but then the page doesnt redirects and gets stuck in the error page.

Comment: @castis : Thanks for the advise . Fixed one error and the rest all are gone :)

Comment: This is not related to MySQL - people with MySQL skills won't be able to help. Therefore I removed the tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 3):

Undefined index -- that's the error you need to resolve here. You're most likely trying to access a property of $_GET or $_POST using an incorrect key name.

For the sake of debugging, try this:

```
if(isset($_GET['keyname'])) {
  $myObj->prop = $_GET['keyname'];
} else {
  show_error('No value set for keyname', 500);
}
```

I'm making a lot of assumptions about your code here, replace *keyname* with whatever you are trying to access.

For reference, you should probably switch to using the [CodeIgniter Input Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) to get values from GET/POST.